# Selectively ignoring JSON properties during deserialize with Jackson

Tags: java, json, performance, jackson

I want to selectively ignore JSON properties during the deserialization phase. I'm currently dealing with a huge JSON file that takes ages to deserialize on slow Android devices and I would like to specify some properties not to be deserialized at different stages of the app lifecycle. The problem is, sometimes I need the data and I need to be able to deserialize the ignored data when I actually need it.

I'm using Jackson and ObjectMapper.

Example POJO:

```
public class Pojo {
    private String name;
    private Map<String, String> data;

    ...
}
```

Example JSON:

```
{
    "pojos" : [ {
        name : "Name",
        data : {
            "somedata1" : "somevalue1",
            "somedata2" : "somevalue2",
            "somedata3" : "somevalue3"
            ...
        }
    } ]
}
```

There will be great amount of "pojos" and each "data" property will get HUGE. So I would like to sometimes deserialize with ignoring the "data" property. Sometimes I want the "data" to deserialize normally.

Comment: We'll need more to go on than that. Wheres the code? Are you using ObjectMapper? Do you have one class? A number of classes? Are you manually deserialising? What are the rules? Whats the data structure? One approach would be to have different classes with different JsonIgnoreProperties annotations but without any information couldn't say.

Comment: I was thinking of the different class approach also but that would mean I need to change my service interface because it relies on the serialized class type. I edited the question with example code and JSON.

Comment: So all your data is always a string map? Not much you can do in that case.

Comment: @Antionio by using different classes you can create a superclass that fits with the class in the service interface and then create 2 or more subclasses...so hopefully nothing should be changed in the service

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Your approach seems to be valid, so if you'd create an official answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using different classes you can create a superclass that fits with the class in the service interface and then create 2 or more subclasses...so hopefully nothing should be changed in the service