# Good practices in REST / Java

Tags: java, json, rest

I'm currently trying to acquire skills in REST, and specifically in "good" Rest, hypermedia and all the good practices that comes with it.

In order to do so, I was asked to develop a prototype REST server containing data of my choice and implementing everything I'll have to use in a real project coming after that. 
So I made a server using Spring boot and Jackson for json handling.

My data architecture is close to this : I have a collection of LaunchVehicle (I like space =D) like Ariane V, Falcon 9, etc. I can retrieve the JSON object flawlessly

```
{ "name":"Ariane V","country":"Europe","firstFlight":null,"GTO_Payload":1.0,"LEO_Payload":2.3,"weight":136.0 }
```

The thing is, I'd like to add a "space agency" field which would be an object containing some Strings and Floats, inside my LaunchVehicle. However, when the client retrieve a LaunchVehicle, I don't want it to retrieve the full SpaceAgency object, just the name for exemple. From here, he would be able to follow the link to the space agency via an hypermedia link included in the response it would have received.

How can I do this ? Right now I'm only able to send to the client my full LaunchVehicle object with the SpaceAgency object and all his fields. Is there any annotations doing what I want ? Thanks ;)

```
public class LaunchVehicle {


    private String name;
    private String country;
    private Date firstFlight;
    private Map<String, Float> characteristics;
    private SpaceAgency spaceAgency;

    @JsonCreator
    constructor...

    @JsonProperty(required=false)
    getters and setters...

}
```

Thanks a lot, don't hesitate if I'm not precise or understandable enough.

Comment: What's the problem with deserializing the entire SpaceAgency and only use the part of it that you like? Performance issue?

Comment: Well, I'm looking for good practices before all right now. I have to use hypermedia, and therefore I was thinking to put the link to the SpaceAgency object in the payload following hypermedia "way-of-doing". This way I wouldn't have to send the complete object in the same request.

Right now I'm just developping a prototype, so no performance issue, but I have do do it right, like this was a really big big application with performance concerns.

Comment: Alright then, have alook at my solution. In your SpaceAgency object, you don't need to delcare all the properties existing in your JSON. Your JSON deserializer should just forget unmapped properties.

Comment: this can also be a possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337589/selectively-ignoring-json-properties-during-deserialize-with-jackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation at the class level. That should provide you the feature that you want.

Otherwise, you could always use some kind of DTO object to create your response model, and there just have the fields that are going to be used at the API layer.

I would rather prefer to use an appropiate DTO/ApiModel for your API layer than having a full domain object with JSON annotations in it.

Comment: Thansk. Concerning the @JsonIgnoreProperties method, I would I let the client read the full SpaceAgency object from another url then ? Wouldn't the fields be ignored then too ?

Comment: If I understand you, that's what I was trying to say with the json annotations inside your model classes. For me, one thing is your application model, and another one is your API model. Your SpaceAgency model class is unique in your application, but you could need to send different "views" (DTO's) depending on your application API

Comment: Furthermore, I would avoid any coupling between your model classes and your API responses. That way you have your model clean of any JSON knowledge, and you can adapt your API responses without changing your model classes if there is no need to

Comment: That's a good idea, I'm going to try that way. I'll let you know, thank you !

Comment: So, I did what you said (DTO classes) and indeed it's doing what I want perfectly with a little bit of computing. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If your SpaceAgency class only defines the properties that you need to deserialize, Jackson will only deserialize those. It will forget the unmapped properties.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I'm looking for. What I would like is a result like this :  `code` { "name":"Ariane, ... , "spaceAgency" : "ESA"}, "_link":{"_self" : ... , "ESA" : "url/api/spaceAgency/ESA" }

Comment: The result you are showing me is a JSON. The JSON is the input in your program not the output, right?

Comment: I take JSON as an input from my client, and I send back the JSON I mentioned earlier as a response.
Anyway I got it working, so I'm happy with that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gson API for this

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject obj = parser.parse(spaceAgency).getAsJsonObject();
String agencyName = obj.get("agencyName").getAsString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jax-ws-rs!
It's a standart REST implementation in Java.

[Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html)

[Very good tutorial by Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reference the space agency as a hyperlink.

So the JSON will look like:

```
{ "name":"Ariane V",
  "country":"Europe",
  < other fields omitted >
  "_links": {
    "agency": { "href": "agencies/ESA" },
   < other links omitted >
  }
}
```

To achieve this you need to specify the link in your data transfer object. Don't make this a reference to an actual object of that type -- to do so would mean populating that object, even when the client doesn't ask for it.

How you achieve this depends on what technology you're using. In Jersey it's

```
 public class LaunchVehicle {
     ...
     @InjectLink(resource=AgencyResource.class)
     URI agencyLink;
     ...
 }
```

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/declarative-linking.html

Linking like this is what "real" REST is all about. However note that plenty of real-world solutions claim to be doing REST without actually using hyperlinks. A more hacky solution would be to have a `String agencyId` field in your JSON, which could be put into a URL template to get agency details.

Comment: NB: Europe is not a country ;)

Comment: Yeah I Know that, I even live in it ^^
This is a test project, I needed a field to put the origin of my space launchers, so "country" was my first thought. That works well for USA, Russia and Japan... Damn us European trying to work together ! :P